# how to merge two manifests in same module by gradle?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have two manifests in one module, one is used as a library for the whole app, another is used as the module's manifest, then this module can run alone. Below is my gradle config:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        if (configs.isIntegrate) {
            //module as app
            manifest.srcFile 'src/main/module/AndroidManifest.xml'
        } else {
            //module as library
            manifest.srcFile 'src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
        }
    }
}
```

so, when I add a new activity, I have to register twice.is this a way I can register
once in manifest below the main dir, then let the manifest that below the main/module dir merge it?

Comment: idk if I understand correctly, but in my experience, you shouldn't need to do that, because all activities across different manifests in module libraries are automatically merged into the final manifest.  To check it, take a look, into your APP MODULE, at `</app_dir>/build/intermediates/manifest/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml` . That's the final, merged Manifest.

Comment: @rupps sorry for my English.Gradle auto merges manifests in different modules. I mean,when configs.isIntegrate is false, the module use the manifest  below main/module dir,when true,the module use the manifest below main dir.But i want that when  configs.isIntegrate is true,the module merge the two menifest.

Comment: ooh I think I understand the question now, but I don't know how to do it :) With my very limited gradle skills I'd try to generate that manifest myself executing a SHELL SCRIPT task first of it all, but I am sure there are better ways to do it.

Comment: @rupps thanks any way.I hope someone can give a gradle way.